# How could I add a row composed of pd.Timestamp and float in a Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to append a row that contains some pandas timestamp and some float value to a dataframe using the following code

```
pair_columns = ['T1 Time', 'T1 Active', 'T1 Reactive', 'T2 Time', 'T2 Active', 'T2 Reactive']

# an empty dataframe
matched_pairs = pd.DataFrame(columns=pair_columns)


# A list with some Timestamp
value_with_timestamp = [pd.Timestamp('2011-10-21 20:08:42+0000', tz='UTC'), 21.847724815467735, -78.998453511820344, pd.Timestamp('2011-10-21 20:08:54+0000', tz='UTC'), -74.608437575303114, 48.537725275212779]
ser_timestamp = pd.Series(value_with_timestamp)


# This pass, but the dataframe get a row containing only NaN
matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = ser_timestamp
print("Dataframe with series containing timestamp")
print(matched_pairs.head())

# Exception TypeError: data type not understood
matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = value_with_timestamp
print(matched_pairs.head())

# Exception TypeError: data type not understood
matched_pairs = matched_pairs.append(ser_timestamp, ignore_index=True)
print(matched_pairs.head())
```

This code doesn't work, but with string instead of Timestamp, everything works right

```
import pandas as pd

matched_pairs_string = pd.DataFrame(columns=pair_columns)

# The same list but with string instend of timestamp
value_string = ['2011-10-21 20:08:42+0000', 21.847724815467735, -78.998453511820344, '2011-10-21 20:08:54+0000', -74.608437575303114, 48.537725275212779]

# Add the list with the string to the dataframe, this work like a charm
matched_pairs_string.loc[len(matched_pairs_string)] = value_string
print("Dataframe with string instead of timestamp")
print(matched_pairs_string.head())
```

What i'm doing wrong here ? Is there a way to accomplish what I want ? I just want to add this data as a row as is instead of convert the timestamp as another type ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, it is not the timestamp that is the problem but what type of object you are assigning to row: a *series* (which you attempt in first code block) vs a *list* (which you attempt in second code block).

Since every column in a pandas DataFrame *is* a pandas Series, you cannot assign a row to a series. Consider converting to a list for row assignment with `series.tolist()` or use the original list:

```
matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = ser_timestamp.tolist()
#               T1 Time  T1 Active  T1 Reactive             T2 Time  T2 Active  T2 Reactive
# 0 2011-10-21 20:08:42  21.847725   -78.998454 2011-10-21 20:08:54 -74.608438     48.53772

matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = value_with_timestamp
#               T1 Time  T1 Active  T1 Reactive             T2 Time  T2 Active  T2 Reactive
# 0 2011-10-21 20:08:42  21.847725   -78.998454 2011-10-21 20:08:54 -74.608438     48.53772
```

And in doing so, you assign proper data types:

```
print(matched_pairs.dtypes)

# T1 Time        datetime64[ns]
# T1 Active             float64
# T1 Reactive           float64
# T2 Time        datetime64[ns]
# T2 Active             float64
# T2 Reactive           float64
# dtype: object
```

---

As OP indicates, there may be a version issue where above in pandas 0.19 throws the exception:

> TypeError: data type not understood

One possible resolution can be explicitly defining data types (timestamp and float) on empty dataframe prior to row assignment. Since there is no single `dtype()` call, a loop is run to convert each column:

```
pair_columns = ['T1 Time', 'T1 Active', 'T1 Reactive', 'T2 Time', 'T2 Active', 'T2 Reactive']
pair_dtypes = ['M8[ms]', 'float', 'float', 'M8[ms]', 'float', 'float']

# an empty dataframe
matched_pairs = pd.DataFrame(columns=pair_columns)
datatypes = {k:v for k,v in zip(pair_columns, pair_dtypes)}

for k,v in datatypes.items():
    matched_pairs[k] = matched_pairs[k].astype(v)

...
matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = ser_timestamp.tolist()
# matched_pairs.loc[len(matched_pairs)] = value_with_timestamp
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't see the difference between our code and mine. If we take the part when I try to assign a pure list to the dataframe row, this attempt was already made. On my system our solution doesn't work (by converting the series or with the pure list), it return a TypeError : data type not understood. The pandas version is 0.19.1 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Hmmm...very interesting. In fact, I did see that next line in first code block using list but with exact posted data, I could not recreate. I use python 3.4, pandas 0.18 on Windows 10. No error occurs. Can you try from another cpu environment? Are you sure this posted example is what you use? Try clean, new session with just this code (not actual project).

Comment: Yeah, you were right, that was an environment issue. The fun fact is that the three environnement that I have tested (2 Ubuntu 16.04, python 2.7.12, pandas 0.19.1 and 1 Windows 10 python 2.7.12 and also pandas 0.19.1) only one of them worked right... thanks you !

Comment: Curious, does it happen on pandas 0.19? python 2.7? I added an update to explicitly define `dtypes` on empty dataframe prior to row assignment. Possibly coercing `pd.Timestamp()` to an `object` (default type) may be the issue.